# Using both nvidia and amd gpu in the same machine

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, amd-graphics

Hi im using a 980ti in slot 1 and a amd 280x in slot 4.
I want to use them both for mining.
I have installed the nvidia drivers and everything is working.
But when I installed the amd drivers and rebooted my computer is stuck at screen flickering. So after a couple of tries to get it to work I just reinstalled ubuntu and am now back at square 1.

Answer (score 1):

This may help, I'm not sure, take a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/113705/155643):

- Load both drivers with `modprobe module-name`
- Get the ID for each amd-device and nvidia-device with `lspci -nn`
- Bind the driver you wish to each device ID with:

  `echo -n "amd-device-ID" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/[amd-driver]/bind`

  `echo -n "nvidia-device-ID" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/[nvidia-driver]/bind`